# Scroll list to top of div using ScrollTo

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I am trying to get a long list of names to work with a navigation (a-z). Clicking on the letter on the navigation will scroll the correct names to the top of the div.

I am using the ScrollTo plugin to get this working. Everything works great, except for the names closer to the bottom of the list. They do not scroll to the top of the div.

Here is my example: jsfiddle.net/QMgMB/

If you click on d, e, f you will see that it works. But clicking on the Q button, the Q name section does not go to the top.

I can't seem to figure out why.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it reach the end of the div. You can't scroll more than possible. You can add some extra "end of line" to simulate your behavior `<br>` like this : http://jsfiddle.net/QMgMB/1/

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. I have decided to use "margin-bottom" on my list instead of the `<br>` tags. I updated my example: http://jsfiddle.net/QMgMB/2/